# Ubuntu 14.04 get Windows 8 to show up

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on what used to be Ubuntu 12.04. I am dual booting with Windows 8.1. I haven't been able to access Ubuntu 12.04 since Windows 8.1 did some updates a few weeks back.

GRUB shows up and I can't see Windows 8.1. How can I add Windows 8 using Boot Repair?

I figured out how to install boot-repair in Ubuntu 14.04 by doing [this workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1267702).

Most important thing: How can I add Windows 8.1 to the GRUB menu using Boot Repair?

Comment: I tried grub customizer. Visibility is already checked.

Comment: Also, I tried adding a Windows 8 entry to grub customizer but I didn't know what to write under "script".

Comment: There is no Windows nor NTFS partitions at all. You must have choosed the erase entire drive install option. Or this bug. Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows.  
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Grub2 was installed without problem.

```
sudo apt-get install grub2-common
sudo update-grub2
```

This will show up as entries.  If the entries are marked with everything currently installed on the boot disk, everything is good and you have no errors.
Below is a tool designed to make your grub boot manager look the way you want to and boot the way you want to.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

You can open by searching on dashboard by pressing the super button.

in tab "General Settings"

visibility check "show menu"

Comment: This was a useful tool for customizing your already fixed boot manager.  May I suggest adding to how you can possibly trouble shoot other possible ideas?